# SequlizeJS connection get timeout frequently

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

We have a project backend running on **NodeJS** / **expressJS** / **SequilizeJS** as a **RESTapi**.
That **RESTapi** connceted to a **VueJS** SPA.

Only 5 people use this system.
Most of the operations are transactions.

We get an error

> SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError: Operation timeout

This is our config object.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.database,
  config.username,
  config.password,
  {
    host: config.host,
    dialect: "mysql",
    pool: {
      max: 20,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    }
  }
);
```

We are certain that our server's memory is not the issue. Because only 5 percent is used.

Where does this error comes from?

Comment: Might be relevant: https://github.com/sequelize/umzug/issues/191

Comment: Try increasing the `acquire` timeout to a higher value.

Comment: My problem was fixed increasing the number of the connections in pool.

Comment: Increasing number of connections worked for me as well.

Answer (score 5):

Change acquire to 60000, It will resolve otherwise you need to recheck that particular query where it is coming.
acquire: 60000

Answer (score 4):

In your code, there must be an opened transaction that was left hanging. Consider this snippet of code

```
const registerUser = async (payload) => {
    try {
        const t = await Sequelize.transaction() // open a transaction
        if (!payload.name) {
          return {error: 'name is required'} // Notice this function ends here but the opened transaction was not committed or rolled-back thereby leaving the transaction hanging
        }
        User.create({name: payload.name, email: payload.email}, {transaction: t})
        Credentials.create({password: payload.password, username: payload.username}, {transaction: t})
        await t.commit() // At this point, all validations were passed and the data was successfully added to the two tables hence the transaction is committed
        return {message: "User successfully created"}
    } catch (error) {
      await t.rollback() // Some error occurred and the transaction was rolled back
      return {error: 'An error occurred when trying to create a user'}
    }
}
```

So whenever a transaction is opened in a function, it needs to either be committed or rolled back. So in the above function, when a user calls that function without a name in the payload, its going to enter that if statement which will return an error without actually either committing or rolling back the transaction

Comment: Just writing to thank you for pointing out that you should pay attention to early `return` and other flow breakers when using transactions. I used transaction in a loop and had an early `continue` that didn't close the transaction opened at the beginning of the loop

Comment: Just one point to the example. The transaction can not be catched if created inside try {} catch(){} block - it's not in catch scope. It need to be placed under the `try`. Order of transactions also might be matter in the migrations code. If you need many transaction to be commited one after other it better to not create it it one place (i.e. one above other), rather create it by requered.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction in the `sequelize` automatically uses the lock. You must manage this lock. Depending on how many database connections each request has, When the number of requests exceeds your specified maximum connection pool, the request will lock the resource and never release it, so **deadlock** will occur.

You can solve the deadlock:

1. Set timeout. Config `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`, `acquire` time in sequelize
2. Use proper [Isolation Level](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/#isolation-levels)
3. Break the transaction into smaller and simpler transactions, Or cache frequent requests
4. Error handling: If a transaction encounters an error, you must release resources properly

Make sure the transaction is cleaned before any return.

```
try{
    if(!condition){
       return false;
    }
    await transaction.commit()
    return true;
} catch (error) {
    await transaction.rollback()
    return error;
} finally {
    await transaction.cleanup();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

May be you are using trasaction in your query if yes use async await rather then .then function may is will resolved if resolved please reply in this post

Comment: It looks more like a comment then answer